# How to access values from columns in DataFrame like ResultSet in JDBC?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, cassandra, apache-spark-sql

Suppose in jdbc i can write `result.getString(1)` for reading each column . Is there any such concept in spark dataframe.

Ex:

```
val ex_table = sqlContext.sql("select  id, name,gender,address from ex_table2 ")
```

I need to extract each column and insert into Cassandra using Cassandra Prepared Statement.

Can any one help me out ?

Answer (score 1):

Your `ex_table` is a `DataFrame` which is a `Dataset[Row]`.

> A Dataset is a strongly typed collection of domain-specific objects that can be transformed in parallel using functional or relational operations. Each Dataset also has an untyped view called a DataFrame, which is a Dataset of Row.

`Dataset` has `foreach` operator (among many others) that gives you access to the underlying `Row`s.

```
ex_table.foreach { row => ... }
```

And given `foreach` operator is used for side-effects like saving to a Cassandra database, you're done.

> **foreach(f: (T) ⇒ Unit): Unit** Applies a function f to all rows.

While inside `foreach` you can access a `Row` (similar to `ResultSet` in JDBC) that has methods like `getAs`:

> **getAs[T](i: Int): T** Returns the value at position i.

Your code would then look like:

```
ex_table.foreach { row => 
  val fieldOne = row.getAs(1)
  // Save the fieldOne and others to Cassandra
}
```

### DataStax Spark Cassandra Connector

I would however recommend using [DataStax Spark Cassandra Connector](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector) package:

> This library lets you expose Cassandra tables as Spark RDDs, write Spark RDDs to Cassandra tables, and execute arbitrary CQL queries in your Spark applications.

Using this library gives you writing your DataFrames as easy as the following:

```
ex_table.
  write.
  format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra").
  options(Map( "table" -> "words", "keyspace" -> "test" , "cluster" -> "ClusterOne")).
  save
```

See [Datasets (Previously DataFrames)](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/doc/14_data_frames.md).

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have a case class as follows:

```
case class Person(id: Int, name: String, gender: String, address: String)
```

So for your query, you could just

```
val results = sqlContext.sql("select id, name,gender,address from ex_table2 ")
val personList = results.map(row => Person(row.getAs[Int]("id"), r.getAs[String]("name"), r.getAs[String]("gender"), r.getAs[String]("address"))
```

Now you could take `personList` and use it to store into Cassandra.